# Issue with keys on Kiln using TRD

Tags: kiln, tezos-reward-distributor

Is it OK to try to use TRD using Kiln? This is my first question. The second one is this:

```
2021-09-25 13:23:24,564 - MainThread - ERROR - Error, request ->http://127.0.0.1:6732/keys/[my_address]<-, params ->None<-,

---
Error, exception ->HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=6732): Max retries exceeded with url: /keys/[my_address] (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f41d2e628e0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))<-
2021-09-25 13:23:24,565 - MainThread - ERROR - Error, request ->http://127.0.0.1:6732/keys/[my_address]<-, params ->None<-,
---
```

The command I try to run is default:

```
python3 src/main.py
```

Any idea what I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use TRD with Kiln, provided you have set up tezos-signer correctly. There is a requirement to use tezos-signer with TRD now. This was done to allow Kiln users to use TRD without needing tezos-client.

The default TRD command makes many assumptions about your setup, ports, and IPs. There's a 95% chance you need to supply many parameters, mainly the RPC port to your local kiln node, and the port/ip to your local tezos-signer instance.

If you are in the baker's slack, please join #trd for support.